# Global Screenupdating deactivate

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project where the Screen should not update while working. 
Unfortunately I need to use a tool by SAP (SAPBEX) that activates this Updating again.

Is there a way to do Application.ScreenUpdating = false globally so that no other functions are able to activate it again?

Comment: What do you mean with "Global"? That the entire OS doesn't update the screen or just Excel?

Comment: Actually just Excel.

Comment: Now, since you don't have a full / code example I don't know what's going on in your solution. What you can do is run the code against a hidden Excel instance: `Dim xlApp as Application` and then use `Set xlApp = New Application` (it's hidden by default.) Next open/close files and do the edits in that instance. Since it'll never show, the screenupdating issue will simply not be there. I'd need a full example to work out a more accurate answer.